# Spring Integration - Get info from 3rd party services using replyChannel

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-integration-dsl

Im new to Spring Integration, I have to get a list of online agents from 3rd party web services, i tried to configure spring integration to get it, but for the `channel` part, i not really sure how to configure it.

My original configuration was the following, i copied from a sample that use to send request to 3rd party web services:

```
public interface WebServiceGateway {

    @Gateway(requestChannel = "getStatusChannel")
    public String getStatus(String var);     <------ being forced to send something
}
```

In my integration configuration,

```
@Configuration
public class IntegrationConfiguration {

   @Bean
    public MessageChannel getStatusChannel() {
        return MessageChannels.direct().get();
    }
}
```

The problem is, im not sending any parameter to the webservices, in `requestChannel` it force me to do so, so i modified the `gateway` part:

```
public interface WebServiceGateway {

    @Gateway(replyChannel = "getStatusChannel")
    public String getStatus();
}
```

This part remains unchanged:

```
@Configuration
public class IntegrationConfiguration {

   @Bean
    public MessageChannel getStatusChannel() {
        return MessageChannels.direct().get();
    }
}
```

It prompted me `java.lang.IllegalStateException: receive is not supported, because no pollable reply channel has been configured`, why can't i use `MessageChannel` as the reply channel? How should i configure the `IntegrationConfiguration`?

Answer (score 0):

Please go through this https://spring.io/blog/2014/11/25/spring-integration-java-dsl-line-by-line-tutorial

All you need is to define an IntegrationFlow like below:

```
IntegrationFlows.from(requestchannel())
                .handle("requestHandler","handleInput")
                .channel(replyChannel())            
                .get();
```